# Android Chronometer format

Tags: android

How can I set Android Chronometer format to HH:MM:SS??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change format of chronometer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152569/how-to-change-format-of-chronometer)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*first proposal - left only for history*

```
Chronometer c;
...
c.setFormat("HH:MM:SS");
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setFormat%28java.lang.String%29

---

*Edit* - This does not work *at all*! Sorry for the too fast, untested answer... 
Here is something that works:

```
Chronometer c;
...    
c.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
        long t = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
        cArg.setText(DateFormat.format("kk:mm:ss", t));
    }
});
```

Comment: It is adding time offset to formatted time, how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 8):

It seems people who posted the previous answers did not even try what they suggested.
It simply does not work the way they described.
Refer to [how to change format of chronometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152569/how-to-change-format-of-chronometer) for more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks! And you are right, the answer had not been tested. The curious thing is that it got accepted...

Answer (score 6):

After some testing, I came up with this code. It's not fully tested but you can provide me with more info if you

```
private void formatChronometerText(Chronometer c) {
    int cTextSize = c.getText().length();
    if (cTextSize == 5) {
        breakingTime.setFormat("00:%s");
    } else if (cTextSize == 7) {
        breakingTime.setFormat("0%s");
    } else if (cTextSize == 8) {
        breakingTime.setFormat("%s");
    }
}
```

I called this method in the `onCreate()` method eg.

```
Chronometer c = ...
...
formatChronometerText(c);
c.setText("00:00:00");
```

I'll be back in a day to verify if it works or it needs to be called also after the size of the text changes. If you are a precautious person I suggest that you call it in the same context with `c.start()` and `c.stop()`

```
if(ticking){
    c.stop();
    formatChronometerText(c);
} else {
    formatChronometerText(c);
    c.start()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
Chronometer chronometer;
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer c) {              
        int cTextSize = c.getText().length();
        if (cTextSize == 5) {
            chronometer.setText("00:"+c.getText().toString());
        } else if (cTextSize == 7) {
            chronometer.setText("0"+c.getText().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

found a better solution with no memory allocation for the String every second:

```
 c.setFormat("00:%s");
 c.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer c) {
            long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -c.getBase();
            if(elapsedMillis > 3600000L){
                c.setFormat("0%s");
            }else{
                c.setFormat("00:%s");
            }
        }
 });
```